# mongoose deleteone resulted 0

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I use mongoose to delete record on mongodb.

This is my record

```
    MongoDB Enterprise > db.contacts.find().toArray();
[
        {
                "_id" : ObjectId("6187ebca4691bb4a3eeeb91d"),
                "nama" : "herahadi",
                "notlp" : "084234234234",
                "email" : "herahadi@gmail.com",
                "__v" : 0
        },
        {
                "_id" : ObjectId("618861aaeeb7aeaf202a1890"),
                "nama" : "izam",
                "notlp" : "08533523232323",
                "email" : "izam@gmail.com",
                "__v" : 0
        }
]
```

My app.js

```
    var methodOverride = require('method-override');    
    .....
    app.delete('/contact',async(req,res)=>{
    console.log('req.body.nama='+ req.body.nama);

    Contact.deleteOne({ nama: req.body.nama }).then((result)=>{
        console.log(result);
        res.redirect('/contact');
    });
```

And this is page that call the delete.

```
<form method="POST" action="/contact?_method=DELETE" class="d-inline">
                    <input type="hidden" name="nama" value="<%= contact.nama %> ">
```

If I run my project, i got this result

```
req.body.nama=izam 
{ deletedCount: 0 }
```

Can someone tell me what is wrong? why the delete result is 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i solved my problem by change to findOneAndDelete() as mentioned by @Naveem. but also have to change req.body.nama into JSON.stringify(req.body.nama) otherwise its still can't delete the record.

so here is my final code

```
app.delete('/contact',(req,res)=>{
    console.log('req.body.nama='+ req.body.nama);
    // const contact = await Contact.findOne({nama:req.body.nama});

    Contact.findOneAndDelete({ nama: JSON.stringify(req.body.nama) }).then((result)=>{
        
        console.log(result);
        res.redirect('/contact');
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return deleted value result, then you should use Mongoose | findOneAndDelete() Function.

The findOneAndDelete() function is used to find a matching document, remove it, and pass the found document (if any) to the callback.

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/mongoose-findoneanddelete-function/

Comment: i change to findOneAndDelete and on console log its resulted null

Comment: I have checked it on my side but I have found some issue while attaching screenshot with that, could you send me some reputation on my profile

Comment: and instead of using app.delete, also try app.post method

Answer (score -1):

Please check both code and the attached screenshot for results.
Screenshot for the terminal result from mongoose query with full user result
1st image
https://i.stack.imgur.com/SrGyL.png

Nodejs code script for find one and delete
2nd image
https://i.stack.imgur.com/IWN9p.png